# How to use an M1 required app on an Intel Mac

Tags: apple-silicon, intel

Lately, I've noticed an abundance of M1 apps on the App Store that I can't download on my Intel Mac (i3).  Is there a way to download these apps or use some other app to un-Rosetta things?  Maybe downloading an older version of the app, but I've read that the App Store doesn't allow you to do that.

Comment: Give us an example (preferably a free one). You can't un-Rosetta, need to find older version of app.

Comment: Are these apps ones ported from iOS? These are ARM only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps that require Apple Silicon cannot be run on Intel computers.